# Is there a way to programatically export jira issues to a word document

Tags: jira

I'm trying to use the "Export to word" feature on Jira, where you can, as it implies, export the currently selected Jira issues, into a word document.

I haven't been able to find any information about this in their API documentation, so i was wondering if anyone here has been able to do this?

Comment: I do not think that JIRA has any native rest API to export the issue in WORD format but they have rest API to provide the ISSUE in JSON format using the following link: https://<JIRA URL>/rest/api/2/issue/<ISSUE-ID>

Comment: Yeah, i've made use of the rest API and build an application to make a word/excel report using the issues from the JSON format, but thought it would be nice if i could've just pressed that button instead, thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

There is no official API, but what you can do is reusing the Word download link from the website, because it is customizable. Simply click right on the link in the dropdown menu and copy the download link. Then you can use and customize the link in your favorite programming language and download Word documents from there. The following example is in Python using `requests`.

```py
import requests

headers = {
    "Authorization": "Bearer " + JIRA_API_TOKEN,
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
}

# For a filter
url = f"{jira_url}/sr/jira.issueviews:searchrequest-word/2/SearchRequest-2.doc?tempMax=1000"

# For a jql search query
url = f"{jira_url}/sr/jira.issueviews:searchrequest-word/temp/SearchRequest.doc?jqlQuery=project+%3D+TEST&tempMax=1000"

# For a single issue
url = f"{jira_url}/si/jira.issueviews:issue-word/TEST-1/TEST-1.doc"

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

with open("test.doc", "wb") as file:
    file.write(response.content)
```

This approach should also work for all other export targets. It's sad, that it is not documented, but works pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution that worked for me

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

username = 'username'
password = 'password'

# Jira API URL for getting the currently authenticated user's details
user_url = "https://jira_server/rest/api/2/myself"

# Set up the request headers
headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}

# Set up the authentication
auth = HTTPBasicAuth(username, password)

# Make the request to get user details
response = requests.get(user_url, headers=headers, auth=auth)

# Check if the request was successful. DisplayName is just to know if you are authenticated
if response.status_code == 200:
    user_data = response.json()
    user_name = user_data['displayName']
    print(f"Authenticated as: {user_name}")

    # For a single issue
    issue_key = "issue"
    attachment_url = f"https://jira_server/si/jira.issueviews:issue-word/{issue_key}/{issue_key}.doc"

    # Make the request to download the file
    attachment_response = requests.get(attachment_url, headers=headers, auth=auth)

    # Check if the request was successful
    if attachment_response.status_code == 200:
 
        # Save the file
        with open(f"{issue_key}.doc", "wb") as file:
            file.write(attachment_response.content)

        print(f"File '{issue_key}' downloaded successfully.")
    else:
        print(f"Failed to download file. Status code: {attachment_response.status_code}, Response: {attachment_response.text}")

else:
    print(f"Authentication failed. Status code: {response.status_code}, response: {response.text}")
```